# HoltWinters() in R with damped trend

Tags: r, forecasting

I have weekly data. As it is not possible to use `ets()` from `forecast` to fit seasonal model with frequency more that 52, I choose to use `HoltWinters()` function which allows me to fit the model with frequency 52.

My question is that can we use `HoltWinters()` along with damped option like we have in `ets()`

```
fit<-ets(x_ts, damped=TRUE)
```

I have been searching a lot regarding this, but did not get anything. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: You should mention that `ets` is from `forecast`.

Comment: In `HotWInters()` can't be use **damped** and **exponential**.